# Javascript function to toggle menu items A, B, C, D

Tags: javascript

I have menu items A, B, C, and D and I want to toggle them when clicked as well as close a previously opened one while opening the clicked one.

1. Clicking A should open A
2. If A is open and I click A again, A closes
3. If I click B adnd A is open, A closes and B opens.

Same functionality for all items.

Comment: Ok. I guess you should be trying yourself to code a solution for your problem, based on your knowledge of the javascript language. Then if you fail, you can share some code, and we can comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if statements and apply different styles or classes.

CSS

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML & JavaScript

```html
<div id="A" class="" onclick="handlePress('A');">A</div>
<div id="B" class="hidden" onclick="handlePress('B');">B</div>
<div id="C" class="hidden" onclick="handlePress('C');">C</div>
<div id="D" class="hidden" onclick="handlePress('D');">D</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

function handlePress(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('hidden');

  letters.forEach((letter) => {
    if (letter !== id) {
      document.getElementById(letter).classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}
</script>
```